# remove duplicate value looping statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hi to all i have a problem, i want to remove the duplicate value from my looping 
eg.

I have a 4 record,
It must be 4 records display from my output, the problem is, it display a 16 records that's why I need to remove duplicate from my looping statement

See my code below

coming from submit

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo "$row[partyid]"; ?>' name='phonenum[]' readonly />
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($phonenum);$i++)
    {



    $sql = "SELECT  * 
            FROM 
                $table2,
                $table3 

            WHERE 
                $table2.billdate = '$date'
                AND $table3.tel_three LIKE '%$phonenum[$i]%' 


    ";
    <?php if( $rs == null ):?>
        <tr>


            <td  align='center'><font size=1>0</font></td>
            <td  align='center'><font size=1>0</font></td>
            <td  align='center'><font size=1>0</font></td>
            <td  align='center'><font size=1>0</font></td>
            <td  align='center'><font size=1>0</font></td>


        </tr>";
    <?php else:?>
        <?php while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs) ):
        ?>
        <tr>

            <form action='flookup.php' method='post'>
            <td  align='center'><?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['billdate']."</font>"; ?></td>
            <td  align='center'><?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['calldate']."</font>"; ?></td>
            <td  align='center'><?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['partyid']."</font>"; ?></td>
            <td  align='center'><?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['billedamount']."</font>"; ?></td>
            <td  align='center'>
                <?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['partyid']."</font>"; ?>
                <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $row['partyid']; ?>" name='phonenum' readonly />
            </td>
            <td  align='center'><?php echo "<font size=1>".$row['value']."</font>"; ?>
            <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $row['value']; ?>" name='sipvalue' readonly />
            <td  align='center'><input type='text' value="<?php echo $row['value']; ?>" name='value' readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: what is the relation between table1 and table2,on what basis u are joining them?

Comment: this is are the relationship $sql = "SELECT  * 
      FROM 
       $table2,
       $table3 
   
      WHERE 
       $table2.billdate = '$date'
       AND $table3.tel_three LIKE '%$phonenum[$i]%'

Comment: that is not the relation,in the query u are joining two tables but u are not providing any columns on which they should be joined.

Comment: You've forgotten `$table1` [/irony]

Comment: my $table1 is the user table...that's why i did not include to my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your SQL statement to add a joining condition between $table2 and $table3

```
$sql = "SELECT  * 
        FROM 
            $table2,
            $table3 

        WHERE 
            $table2.billdate = '$date'
            AND $table3.tel_three LIKE '%$phonenum[$i]%'
            AND $table2.something = $table3.something
        ";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i will try...but the problem is my two table doesn't have the same column name.

Comment: The columns may have distinct names, but you should have a joining condition or the result will be the cartesian produce of rows in $table2 and rows in $table3

Comment: i have additional sql statement here AND $table2.party = $table3.tel_three but the problem is the value of table2 is not the same in table3 that's why in my query i put wildcard, table2 value=209152323 table3 value =9152323 you see the difference..

Comment: hi i make it but my another problem also the table header, it has been loop also here's my code $sql = "SELECT  * 
      FROM 
       $table2,
       $table3 
   
      WHERE 
       $table2.billdate = '$date'
    AND $table2.partyid = '$phonenum[$i]'
       AND $table3.tel_three LIKE '%$phonenum[$i]%' 
    
      
 ";

Comment: your table headers (and your form tag probably) should be outside the while loop to be printed just once